# Can't find the File Owner icon

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

I have created a small IOS app using the Single View application template, for my view, i can't find the `File Owner` icon.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since a storyboard is not loaded with an owner, there is no file's owner in a storyboard.